# Same endpoint (Bing Visual Search API) but different result from Python script and PHP script

Tags: python, php, php-curl, bing, bing-api

The image I am using
[image: testing image]

Python script:

```py
HEADERS = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': SUBSCRIPTION_KEY}
file = {'image' : ('myfile', open(imagePath, 'rb'))}
def print_json(obj):
        """Print the object as json"""
        print(json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
    
try:
        response = requests.post(BASE_URI, headers=HEADERS, files=file)
        response.raise_for_status()
        print_json(response.json())
        
except Exception as ex:
        raise ex
```

Python script results: https://pastebin.com/3N3BTgPU

PHP Script:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
$img = curl_file_create($imagepath);
$post = ["image" => $img];
    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ' . self::API_KEY,
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
echo "$contents";
```

PHP Script results: https://pastebin.com/c2tKwgBV

Results from Bing Visual Search: [here](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&insightstoken=bcid_SxaPkHtr0DwCF34aJ6BN6WsQjZGj.....zE*ccid_Fo%2BQe2vQ&form=SBIVSP&iss=SBIUPLOADGET&sbisrc=ImgPicker&idpbck=1&sbifsz=745%20x%20715%20%C2%B7%2037.37%20kB%20%C2%B7%20jpeg&sbifnm=WhatsApp%20Image%202021-01-05%20at%2000.42.28.jpeg&thw=745&thh=715&ptime=78&dlen=51020&expw=612&exph=587&selectedindex=0&id=1062658415&ccid=Fo%2BQe2vQ&vt=2&sim=1)

I can confirm that both scripts use the same endpoint, API Key and same image.
What am I doing wrong in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know PHP but are you sure you are passing the same payload to the post endpoint in both case? Try printing the both payloads and compare.

Python:

```
# a dict with key and value(a tuple with 'myfile' and image)
file = {'image' : ('myfile', open(imagePath, 'rb'))}
```

PHP:

```
# a list (?)
$post = ["image" => $img];
```

Comment: Thanks!, chaning to `$img = curl_file_create($imagepath, "image/jpg", "myfile");` solved the problem.